# Как установить свой user-agent в URLOpenBlockingStream

Tags: c++

У меня есть функция

```
auto URLDownloadBinary(LPCSTR lpszURL, BYTE **ppBuffer, DWORD *pdwSize) -> 
int
{
LPSTREAM lpStream = 0;
BYTE *pResult = 0;
int nResult = 0;

if (lpszURL && SUCCEEDED(URLOpenBlockingStream(NULL, lpszURL, &lpStream, 0, NULL)))
{
    STATSTG statStream;
    if (SUCCEEDED(lpStream->Stat(&statStream, STATFLAG_NONAME)))
    {
        DWORD dwSize = statStream.cbSize.LowPart;
        pResult = (BYTE *)malloc(dwSize);
        if (pResult)
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER liPos;
            ZeroMemory(&liPos, sizeof(liPos));
            lpStream->Seek(liPos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL);
            lpStream->Read(pResult, dwSize, NULL);
            *ppBuffer = pResult;
            *pdwSize = dwSize;
            nResult = 1;
        }
    }
    lpStream->Release();
}

return nResult;
}
```

и я не могу понять как задать здесь свой user-agent

Comment: Видимо, никак. Пользуйтесь другим API, например WinHTTP.

Comment: ну мол я знаю только как так реализовать закачку файла в массив байтов, если вы знаете как по другому можно, то можете поделиться ?

Comment: По другому можно разными способами. Например так: [Downloading Resources from the Web](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/winhttp-sessions-overview#downloading-resources-from-the-web)

Comment: это же чтение страницы, а у меня надо закачку файла в массив байтов, например :0x80, 0x32, 0x9C ...

Comment: Нет никакой разницы что загружать, страницу или файл. Если посмотрите внимательнее, то увидите, что в примере загрузка так же происходит в массив байт, который уже потом выводится на печать. Естественно, пример вам нужно адаптировать под свои нужды. Если вы ищите готовое решение, то задайте отдельный вопрос, может кто-то и поможет.

Comment: я не очень понял что надо изменить что бы записать байты